# How can I find patterns when applying a filter to a list?

Tags: python, filter

I am applying a filter to find a list of folders that comply some conditions.

For example, when I have several folders with names like a_1_1_1 ,a_2_2_2 I do

```
folders = list(filter(lambda x: os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, x)) and x[1]=='_', os.listdir(d)))
```

where d is the base folder.

Then if I have some folder with several subfolders with names like ab_1_1_1 and ab_1_2_3
I have to change the above with

```
folders = list(filter(lambda x: os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, x)) and x[2]=='_', os.listdir(d)))
```

This is cumbersome and not general , so I would like to replace the `x[n]=='_'` condition with something more general'  For example list folders that have three `_` with numbers after the `_`.

How can I introduce this pattern to the expression? (I heard regular expressions but I don't know how)

Comment: do you want to filter out names such as `a_1_1` (because it doesn't have 3 numbers after `_`)?

Comment: yes, ideally it has to have three numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One implementation could be to use `split` on `"_"` and see if what you get is length 4 all (except the first split part) are numbers using `all`:

```
out = list(filter(lambda x: os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, x)) and len(x.split('_'))==4 and all(i.lstrip('-').isdigit() for i in x.split('_')[1:]), os.listdir(d)))
```

But I think it might be more readable to write it using a for-loop instead of `filter`:

```
out = []
for x in os.listdir(d):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(d, x)):
        s = x.split('_')[1:]
        if len(s) == 3 and all(i.lstrip('-').isdigit() for i in s):
            out.append(x)
```

Comment: I just realize this works only for positive numbers...sorry I didn't mention that.. I inserted a small function instead of `isdigit`

Comment: @KansaiRobot I edited the answer to account for negative numbers. See if it works now.